# Meeting Workspace Documents storage

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, meeting-workspace

I have a custom meeting workspace template that we use to create our meeting workspaces. we have a recurring meeting that occurs every week. where do the documents for all these meeting are stored and how they are organized in the meeting workspace.

When I click for documents in a specific meeting date only documents for that meeting show up though we are pointing to a common document library.

when I click on anothe rday of meeting where there are no documents, none show up but both the links are pointing to same document library in meeting workspace.

Is there any way that I can see all the documents irrespective of the day of meeting that I come from? or am I missing something

Thanks,